# JFreeChart Vertical Label for IntervalMarker

Tags: java, rotation, jfreechart, marker

I would like to rotate the label for the IntervalMarker:

```
        IntervalMarker im = new IntervalMarker(...);
        im.setLabel("LABEL");
//      im.setLabelOffsetType(LengthAdjustmentType.EXPAND);
//      im.setLabelOffset(new RectangleInsets(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)); 
//      im.setLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, 11));
        im.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
        im.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
        im.setPaint(new Color(208, 194, 214));
```

It didn't allow me to upload a picture, here is the link:
http://i54.tinypic.com/5z40fs.png

I would like to have "LABEL" vertical, for better looks.

Thank you

Comment: The link image doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I've found it easier to add Text Annotations to vertical markers for more control over their labels. Here's an example:

```
// vertical line marker and label
Marker updateMarker = new ValueMarker(dayOf, Color.black, dashedStroke, null, null, 1.0f);    
XYTextAnnotation updateLabel = new XYTextAnnotation("Update", dayOf - labelOffset, labelHeight);
updateLabel.setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.BOLD, 10));
updateLabel.setRotationAnchor(TextAnchor.BASELINE_CENTER);
updateLabel.setTextAnchor(TextAnchor.BASELINE_CENTER);
updateLabel.setRotationAngle(-3.14 / 2);
updateLabel.setPaint(Color.black);
plot.addDomainMarker(updateMarker, Layer.BACKGROUND);
plot.addAnnotation(updateLabel);
```

This rotation makes the label appear on the left side of the vertical marker line reading bottom-to-top. I use variables "labelOffset" and "labelHeight" to determine the exact position of the label in relation to the vertical line, but these could be set statically as well.

Comment: Fantastic. This helped a lot. Just one comment: `x` and `y` coordinates in `XYTextAnnotation` constructor does not refer to pixels or absolute positions in chart. It refers to the values previously set in `XYSeries`, which it makes very easy to calculate the coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Rendering the marker's label is handled by the `draw{Domain|Range}Marker()` method of the plot's renderer using `drawAlignedString()`. You'd have to use `drawRotatedString()`, instead.

Comment: Is this done by using TextUtilities.drawRotatedString(...) or some other way? Would it be possible to provide an example or link?

Comment: Yes; [`SimulationPlot`](https://github.com/openrocket/openrocket/blob/master/swing/src/net/sf/openrocket/gui/plot/SimulationPlot.java) is typical.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find how to do this directly, but you can always put a rotated text Annotation in an appropriate place.